# OutOfMemoryException - how to find memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a WinForm application. When running it for a long time wihout stopping, it suddenly raise a OutOfMemoryException. I don't know how to find the reason which causes this exception. I use Task Manager to see how much memory my application to use, I see that it only take 90000 KB while my RAM is 2GB. I don't know it is a memory leak error? If yes, I remember there are some .NET tools to help finding the memory leak.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: These findings of mine may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758444/understanding-memory-performance-counters

Answer (score 4):

If you run your application through **WinDbg** you will be able to get a break down of all the objects in memory. A unusually large number will pin point the exact object that is causing this behavior.

You can [follow these instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx)

In a nut shell you do

1. Attach WinDbg to process
2. Issue **.load SOS.dll** command
3. Issue [**!dumpheap –stat**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks.aspx) to view managed objects

Comment: WinDbg is not easy to use but it's very powerful tool. +1.

Answer (score 1):

### [vmmap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533)

A useful tool to see how much and what kind memory your process is using.

### [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273)

Provides a graphical view of the heap and what is holding on to what.  It can be a bit slow, but if the leak is in the managed heap it will point out what types are the problem pretty easily.  [Here's a guide](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2009/03/13/speedy-c-part-4-using---and-understanding---clr.aspx).

### [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)

Like parapura mentioned, this is will let you find your leak, but there's a steep learning curve (and almost no gui).